# What's the meaning of I've got no room?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the quote from the American TV drama *Manifest.*

The police were about to send a criminal who was dying to the hospital nearby, the conversation below took place between two policemen:

> A: Where are you taking him?
>
> B: Mercy.
>
> B: **I've got no room.** We got a uni riding with him already.
>
> A: I can follow behind. But he can't go to Mercy.

What's the meaning of  **I've got no room.**?

Answer (score 1):

B is telling A that there is **no empty seat left** in the vehicle in which B is riding and taking the prisoner to Mercy hospital. This is because already a uniformed officer (a policeman) is riding along with them.